# C++ Qt - QPixmap does not load with Qt Creator, but load when run via terminal

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qpixmap

I am coding a GUI using Qt. When I run the application using `QtCreator`, my images do not load, and I receive the following error:

```
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
```

Yet, when I run the application via command line, everything displays perfectly.

Why so? And how can I get `QtCreator` to load my images properly?

NB: Those images are barely 20ko each, so what I read about images being too big can't apply.

EDIT: A typical filename is `'Images/Cards/Base/card01.jpg'`, where `Images` is a subdirectory of my project directory (the code being at the root)

Comment: Is there a difference in relative path names to the pixmap filename, between QtCreator, and the command line? What do your pixmap filenames look like? Are you using resource files?

Comment: There should be no difference in the relative path, because the images are in the same project directory as the code. Here is an example of path: Images/Cards/Base/card01.jpg 
I do not use resource file. What are those?

Comment: QtCreator use out-of-source build usually. Even if you changed this behavior you have problem with paths. Try to set full path and you will see that you have correct behavior in QtCreator. And it is better to use resources to not have headache with paths.

Comment: You are right, I need to put the full path. I am going to use resources. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with images that should be bundled with the application, such as icons, then you should try and make use of the [Qt Resource system](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/resources.html).

This allows you to build the resources into the actual project and reference them in a filesystem independent syntax. i.e.: `:/icons/myIcon.png`

Most likely you have a difference between the relative location of the file in Qt Creator vs the command line.

Comment: Thank you - I will definitely use resources!